# Disable VM provisioning when an Azure budget alert is triggered

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-policy

In order to monitor and regulate cost spending on my Azure subscription, I am looking at enforcing Azure policy to disable all resource types on my subscription when my Budget alert condition is met.  Please suggest what options are available.

One approach I was looking at was to configure my alert condition to invoke an Action group that calls an Azure function that enforces the policy.  I am new to Azure.  'Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: I suggest you ask this at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: I won't suggest that you do this. This will require for you to put a deny to all resource types so it won't allow creation or updates. Plus you will have to make sure you disable the policy once there is a new budget or you won't be able to create/update anything.